# Angularjs localstorage with object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I need to store json object into angularjs local storage. In my case when ever the push notification receive from GCM I need to store into local storage object and i need to display in one separate page, I have done this by below code

```
var sessionmessages = [];
var notification = {
    "local": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "ldata": {
        "Nick": "Mario",
        "body": "great match!",
        "Room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
    };
    sessionmessages.push(notification);

    var notification1 = {
    "server": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "sdata": {
        "Nick": "Mario",
        "body": "great match!",
        "Room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
};
sessionmessages.push(notification1);
$localstorage.set('mrksesionnotifi', sessionmessages);
console.log($localstorage.getObject('mrksesionnotifi')); // error like Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

My factory like below,

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}])
```

But when i store object array into localstorage i could not get back it, getting error like (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1). Please help anyone to get expected result.

Comment: You implemented `setObject` to write an object to localStorage, but you are using the plain `set` method instead, which wouldn't be able to write the object correctly

Comment: try this module for local storage,http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/html5-local-storage-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

```
var sessionmessages = [];
var notification = {
    "local": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "ldata": {
        "Nick": "Mario",
        "body": "great match!",
        "Room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
};
sessionmessages.push(notification);

var notification1 = {
"server": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
"sdata": {
    "Nick": "Mario",
    "body": "great match!",
    "Room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
};
sessionmessages.push(notification1);
$localstorage.setItem('mrksesionnotifi', sessionmessages);
console.log($localstorage.getItem('mrksesionnotifi'));
```

try this code